# JS add value in iframe

Tags: javascript, arrays, iframe

I am trying to find a way to add a value in a current iframe to submit and resolve hCaptcha.

Currently i can get the iframe using the following:

> document.querySelector('[title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge"]')

Due to there is no id, but am able to locate the iframe with the provided code above.

I however cannot find a way due to I am not a JS coder to enter a value for "data-hcaptcha-response" that is in the iframe that i require to enter before i submit the form.

Full iframe code:

```
<iframe src="xyz" 
 title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge" 
 tabindex="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-hcaptcha-widget-id="0zlooj2ooak" 
 data-hcaptcha-response="" style="width: 303px; height: 78px; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

I highly appreciate it if someone could guide me to do this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job I guess:

```
let hcaptcha = document.querySelector('[title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge"]');
hcaptcha.dataset.hcaptchaResponse = "your_value_here";
```

You can learn more about about using data attributes in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a set value to an attribute.
Try this code, I think this will resolve your issue.

```
document
.querySelector('[title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge"]')
.setAttribute("data-hcaptcha-response", "value of hcaptcha");
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Can you share the complete snippet?

Comment: document
.querySelector('[title="widget containing checkbox for hCaptcha security challenge"]')
.setAttribute("data-hcaptcha-response", "[[CAPTCHA_RESPONSE]]");